# Postgresql 9.5 Installation error

Tags: postgresql, installation

Installing postgresql 9.5 on windows 7,

I had postgresql 9.1 on same machine and uninstalled the same,through control panel-->uninstall program,

After that I tried installing postgresql-9.5.10-1-windows-x64,I get warning:

> database cluster initialization failed postgresql 9.5

from the Users\AppData\Local\Temp\install-postgresql.log I get following error:

> initdb: could not re-execute with restricted token: error code 3
>   The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the
>   same directory as "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin/initdb.exe".
>   Check your installation.

I tried the below solution but it didn't work:

https://webkul.com/blog/postgresql-windows-installation-problem-running-post-install-step-installation-may-not-complete-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

Checked the logs of antivirus

Issue was with Mcafee antivirus, it was blocking the execution of intidb.exe

**Disabled the antivirus and installation went smoothly.**